# Show number of reviews in the impact section of the activity tab

Tags: discussion, feature-request, activity-tab

With the new Activity tab, we got this little Impact section that also shows some statistics regarding a user's contribution to the moderation of the site.

[image]

However, what is also a big part of this contribution, but not shown, is the amount of reviews someone has done. I think this is at least as interesting as, for instance,  the number of posts a user has edited.

Would this be an interesting thing to add? If so, can it be added?

Comment: Is the number of reviews part of the calculation for people reached? If not, it could be misleading...

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan no, the amount of people reached is based off an estimate of how many people visited your questions and questions where you wrote "highly ranked" answers

Comment: Ah, so the edited, helpful flags and votes cast also have nothing to do with people reached either. Interesting. Thanks.

Comment: Correct, it shows in the tooltip when you hover over the number

Answer (score 13):

Yes, that would work:

[image]

There is quite a lot of free space available. The lower margin is a little smaller, so that the 4 lines are not too close together. That shouldn't be a break in the design since the same thing is done in the first reputation card (at least on meta).

I borrowed the `.icon-eye` symbol, but there should be a new one.

Comment: Exactly what I had in mind, neat!

Comment: The number should probably be the total number of reviews, not only the public ones.