# How can you find the number of reviews you have done so far?

Tags: support, review-queues, profile-page

I can not find any section in my profile that shows the number of my reviews. Is there any way to find it out?

Comment: There is [a feature request](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291498/show-number-of-reviews-in-the-impact-section-of-the-activity-tab) to show the number in the "impact" section of the profile. Hopefully some day...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find the total number of your reviews by going to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1600305/ormoz?tab=activity).  Which is just going to your activity page, clicking on "all actions" and then clicking on "reviews". Notice how it says you have done 220 reviews.

[image]